# What is a stable $(n,1)$-category?

Tags: higher-category-theory, infinity-categories

My question in its simplest form is whether we have any understanding of stable $(n,1)$-categories, by analogy with stable $(\infty,1)$-categories and abelian categories (the latter being like "stable $(1,1)$-categories"). It seems like there is a very natural way to begin generalizing: the basic example of a stable $(n,1)$-category should be the $(n,1)$-category of symmetric monoidal $(n-1,0)$-categories with inverses, and then a stable $(n,1)$-category should be something enriched over this with a $0$ object, biproducts, kernels and cokernels, and some property relating the kernels and cokernels.

Obviously this could be a hard question for general $n$, but do we understand even the $n=2$ case? Here the typical stable $(2,1)$-category would be the $(2,1)$-category of Picard groupoids.

And what about stable $(n,r)$-categories? (For example, what about the 2-category of symmetric monoidal categories with inverses?)

Comment: Picard groupoids form an abelian 2-category in the sense of Pirashvili, Vitale & co. However I don't quite agree with you taking abelian categories for $n=1$. I'd take triangulated categories, which is what stable infty-categories enhance.

Comment: Maybe calling them "stable 1-categories" was a poor choice of notation, but I want the basic example to be the category of symmetric monoidal sets with inverses (aka abelian groups), which is not a triangulated category. This is the property that I was hoping to generalize.

Comment: @Fernando: triangulated categories seems wrong to me. Being stable is a property of an $(\infty, 1)$-category, but being triangulated is a structure on a category. Whatever "stable $(n, 1)$-category" means it also ought to be a property, not a structure (so at least abelian satisfies this criterion).

Comment: In any case, $(n, 1)$-categories are already $(\infty, 1)$-categories so we can just apply the definition of stability we already have. But I think we get that the zero category is the only stable $(1, 1)$-category (or something like that), for example.

Comment: @QiaochuYuan $\pi_0$ of a stable infty-category is triangulated. Anyway, all this is speculation.

Comment: I guess you could find examples of what you want by picking a $t$-structure on a stable $(\infty,1)$-category, and looking at the full subcategory of objects with $X\approx t_{\leq n}t_{\geq0} X$.

Comment: BTW, let me mention, in case you find it interesting, that there is a purely algebraic notion of $2$-ring whose modules form an abelian $2$-category. These $2$-rings model ring spectra with htpy groups concentrated in degree $0$ and $1$. They represent classes in third MacLane cohomology.

Comment: This is  developed in Lurie's SAG in C.5 . Available at his homepage.